# Script is re-reading arguments

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting

When I supply the script with the argument: hi[123].txt it will do exactly what I want.
But if I specify the wildcard character ( hi*.txt ) it will be re-reading some files.

I was wondering how to modify this script to fix that silly problem:

```
#!/bin/sh

count="0"
total="0"
FILE="$1"  #FILE specification is now $1 Specification..

for FILE in $@
do
  #if the file is not readable then say so
     if [ ! -r $FILE ];
         then
         echo "File: $FILE not readable"
     exit 0
     fi


# Start processing readable files
  while read line
          do

             if [[ "$line" =~ ^Total ]];
                 then
                   tmp=$(echo $line | cut -d':' -f2)

                   total=$(expr $total + $tmp)

                   echo "$FILE (s) have a total of:$tmp "
                   count=$(expr $count + 1)

             fi

        done < $FILE
done
echo " Total is: $total"
echo " Number of files read is:$count"
```

Comment: After your first if block, add: echo $FILE.  Are there duplicate files being printed?

Comment: Get rid of most of that code and reduce it to the most simple loop you can. Like strager says, have it print.  Start small and working and then grow it.

Comment: I'll second (or third) strager's debugging suggestion.

Comment: This is awfully close to the same question as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/326942/modifying-the-file-specification which @lampshade asked yesterday.  I'm tempted to close this as a duplicate - though the problem is slightly different.

Comment: It also appears that @lampshade has not read the answers to the previous question - points like 'use "$@" instead of $* or $@" have not been listened to.  Also, the tail of y'day's question talks about rereading of files.

Comment: @Jonathan I think it's perfectly fine for one piece of code to have two problems that come up as two different questions. (but yes, should probably start with suggested corrections).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On error, exit with a non-zero status.  Also on error, report errors to standard error, not standard output - though that may be a bit advanced for you as yet.

```
echo "$0: file $FILE not readable" 1>&2
```

The 1 is theoretically unnecessary (though I remember problems with a shell implementation on Windows if it was omitted).  Echoing the script name '`$0`' at the start of the error message is a good idea too - it makes error tracking easier later when your script is used in other contexts.

I believe this Perl one-liner does the job you are after.

```
perl -na -F: -e '$sum += $F[1] if m/^Total:/; END { print $sum; }' "$@"
```

I understand that you are learning shell programming, but one of the important things with shell programming is knowing which programs to use.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what is wrong with it, but one little point i noticed:

Change `for FILE in $@` into `for FILE in "$@"` . Because if files have embedded spaces, you are now on the safe way. It will expand into `"$1" "$2" ...` then, instead of `$1 $2 ...` (and note everywhere you use $FILE too remember to `""` it).

And what others say, you don't need to initialize `FILE` before you enter the loop. It will be set to each of the filenames of the expanded positional parameters in the for loop automatically.

However, i would go with an awk script like this:

```
awk -F: '
/^Total/ { 
    total += $2
    # count++ not needed. see below
    print FILENAME "(s) have a total of: " $2
} 

END { 
    print "Total is: " total
    print "Number of files read is: " (ARGC-1) 
}' foo*.txt
```

Note that when a file contains multiple "^Count" lines, you would indeed say you read more files than you actually read if you rely on `count` to tell you the number of files read.

Comment: I'll second that, you almost always want "$@" over the alternatives when processing files.

Answer (score 1):

This seems redundant:

```
FILE="$1"  #FILE specification is now $1 Specification..

for FILE in $@
  ...
```

The initial assignment is promptly overwritten.

On the whole this seems to be a task better suited to a line processing language like awk or perl.

Consider something along the lines of this awk script:

```
BEGIN{
   TOTAL=0;
   COUNT=0;
   FS=':';
}
/^Total/{
   TOTAL += $2;
   COUNT++;
   printf("File '%s' has a total of %i",FILENAME,TOTAL);
}
END{
   printf("Total is %i",TOTAL);
   printf("Number of files read is%i",COUNT);
}
```

Comment: oops it took me so long to finish my script just to find out how to get the number of files read :) and i thought i would come up with the first one, but you were faster. thumbs up. our solutions look quite the same way. tho your number-of-files will be wrong if there are >1 "^Total" in one file :)

Comment: oh nvm, the OP did the same thing :) haha maybe *that* was his bug. lol

Comment: Methinks your approach is probably right, but I just wrote mine to match the intent I read from the OP. Hey! I see "(ARGC -1)". Nice.

Answer (score 0):

How about this solution:

```
for FILE in `/bin/ls $@`
do
. . .
```

This will effectively eliminate duplicates because `/bin/ls hi1.txt hi1.txt hi1.txt` should only show `hi1.txt` once.

Though I'm not sure why it's re-reading files.  The wildcard expansion should only include each file once.  Do you have some files matched by `hi*.txt` that are links to files matched by `hi[123].txt`?

Comment: And what happens when a file has spaces in it or when there is a file named -l?

Comment: using ls to iterate over files like that isn't a good option. better use "for FILE in *" (assuming you want the files in the CWD) since it will work even if there are spaces in the files names.